# LeafletJS & Ionic disable map watermark

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet

I want to erase the leaflet watermark that overlaps everything below my map display. I don't mind having it in if it was not overlaying other controls in my app.

Answer (score 2):

So, I found the critical parts:

1. Edit your leaflet.js and remove `<a href="http://leafletjs.com" title="A JS library for interactive maps">Leaflet</a>`
2. Edit the `angular-leaflet-directive.js` and remove `&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors`

Hope I'm not violating any copyrights here. Please let me know if that's the case...